# how to insert time in a textbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want the users insert hour and minutes by them selves into a textbox in asp .net.I want when they insert hour,automatically ":" appears and cursor jump over the ":" so user can insert minute. Is there a method for this aim?

Comment: Are you trying to implement a clock? else please add some more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can just drop in a plane jane textbox, like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="Time"></asp:TextBox>
```

If you set the above text mode, then you get a box in which you can type in the hours, it shows : and you don't have to hit tab or anything. In the next area, you then get to type in minutes, and then it jumps to AM/PM, you can type a A or P.

So the whole time entry can be done via keyboard, it looks like this:

[image]

So if you type in 06 it will jump to minutes, and same goes for minutes section.

This takes zero code and is built into asp.net

So try the TextMode="Time" for a regular text box